# How to find a string is Json or not using Jansson?

Tags: c++, json

I am using Jansson.

```
bool ConvertJsontoString(string inputText, string& OutText)
{
    /* Before doing anything I want to check
       if the inputText is a valid json string or not */ 
}
```

Comment: The c++ standard has no notion of valid json syntax, You need to write your own parser if your library doesn't support such function.

Comment: [Google it](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#safe=off&q=c%2B%2B+verify+json+).

Comment: We are here to help with issues, here there is no issue, work is just not done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you read the [documentation](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.7/apiref.html#c.json_loads) where it clearly states:

```
json_t *json_loads(const char *input, size_t flags, json_error_t *error)
    Return value: New reference.

    Decodes the JSON string input and returns the array or object it contains, 
    or NULL on error, in which case error is filled with information about the error. 
    flags is described above.
```

Also they even provide an [example](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.7/tutorial.html#the-program) on how to use this:

```
root = json_loads(text, 0, &error);
free(text);

if(!root)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: on line %d: %s\n", error.line, error.text);
    return 1;
}
```